# ScriptableObjects in Editor and Compiled Project

Tags: unity-game-engine

So the docs are a little vague about it so I wanted to double-check that I understand **Scriptables** right:

- In Unity Editor if I change my **ScriptableObjects'** data (in Play Mode or manually) those changes will persist.
- When the project is compiled and published the data from **ScriptableObjects** is saved into the compiled project. This data can be accessed and even edited. But **all the data** in all **ScriptableObjects** is **reloaded each session back** to its "compiled" state. Am I correct?
- So if compile the project that has **Coins** ScriptableObject with the value of **0**, then those **Coins** data can be seen and edited but it is still **reloaded back to 0** **each play session**. Is that right?

Did I understand everything correctly?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. If you want to save the data of the SO between game sessions, you will have to serialize the data manually. Depending on your needs, you can use the [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) class or third party libraries. Keep in mind that saving references to gameObjects / assets within SO is not trivial.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am bad at english, so can you tell me, please, what do you mean by saying "not trivial"? :)

Comment: By trivial, I meant "easy". To keep things simples, when serializing your SO referencing a gameObject / asset. You are only serializing the ID of the object. This ID is set each time the object is created. Meaning every time the game is started, this ID might be different.